# Menu items links should navigate to default language instead of current language in a multilanguage page

Tags: routes

I am using i18n module and I have a page in spanish language. So when I navigate to other pages in the website then, my url will be like `http://mysite.com/es/about`. In that spanish page, I have added few menu items. The menu items links should defaults to English language instead of the current selected (spanish) language. Please help. Thanks

Comment: So, how exactly you configured it?  Menu items are by full URL? node/nid? What is your order of language decisions? URL first? Session first?.. There are many (too many, maybe) ways to set this up, and we need to know yours to be able to tell for sure.

Comment: Menu item url is node/nid and the order of language decision is URL(first) and then Session.

Comment: Please remember you can edit your question to provide details like that. Is the nid already substituted in the menu, making elements lead to wrong language? Or links are as you want them, but redirection occurs later?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your suggestion and I will do it. I have given the menu url as node/119 and in the "Multilingual Settings", I have selected "Fixed language" and chosen "English" in the language dropdown. So, when I click the menu items, instead of `http://mysite.com/es/about`, it should redirect to `http://mysite.com/about`. I think now you somewhat clear on my question.